# Change the FK to the Null Value if the table which contains the PK was deleted

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have two tables in my DB

> Collection_ (  #Id_Collection,   Libelle_Collection,   Id_Editeur_Editeur  )
>
> Editeur (  #Id_Editeur,   Libelle_Editeur  )

When I want to delete some record from the table "Editeur", it gives me this error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Collection_Id_Editeur_Editeur". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Gestion_bib", table "dbo.Collection_", column 'Id_Editeur_Editeur'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I know that the error because the foreign key in the Collection_ table is a PK in the Editeur table, I was using the Cascade statement in another DB but i had problems with it so I don't prefer to work with it also I used another method using ADO.Net :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myClass.ds.Tables["Collection_"].Rows.Count; i++)
                        if (valToDelete == myClass.ds.Tables["Collection_"].Rows[i][2].ToString())
                            myClass.ds.Tables["Collection_"].Rows[i][2] = DBNull.Value;
                    SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                    adapter.Update(myClass.ds, "Editeur");
```

but this method is getting complicated when I handle with tables that contains many FK.

So, please is there any other method to change the FK to the Null Value if I deleted the table which contains the PK ??

Comment: One of the possible cascade actions is `ON DELETE SET NULL`. Is that the option you say you don't want to use?

Comment: Do you really want to orphan your data? What effect will this have on other queries where your join will no longer work?

Comment: There's no need for a trigger. As @Martin commented, you can define the FK with `ON DELETE SET NULL` option.

Comment: I think the problem goes deeper than that. The entire purpose of having a foreign key constraint in the first place, is to insure that if you have a record in table A you also have a corresponding record in table B. If that is not the case in the OP's situation, he should consider removing the constraint alltogether.

Comment: @Kevin - That seems to be an argument that could be applied against any kind of cascading FK constraint. At least whilst it is in there it prevents inserts and updates that violate the constraint and gives the query optimiser some information about the data in the two tables.

Comment: @Martin Smith yes that's the CASCADE I don't want to use because I had problems with it with a different DB

Comment: @Jodrell I'm using LEFT JOIN because in my situation there is some records that can be have a null value n the FK

Comment: @Kevin what do you mean by "the OP's situation" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using SQL Query:

```
Update Collection_ SET  Id_Editeur_Editeur = NULL WHERE  Id_Editeur_Editeur IN 
(CommaSeperatedValuesToDelete);
```

Then,

```
Delete From Editeur  Where Id_Editeur IN (CommaSeperatedValuesToDelete);
```

Comment: Might want that in a transaction

Comment: I think it's the same method I did using ADO.NET, The deference is that I'm using the disconnected mode, I heard that I can use a trigger but I don't know how.